# 正規表現の先読み/後読みで直近の文字列を対象にするようにしたい

Tags: 正規表現, perl, sed, awk, grep

### 実現したいこと

次のようなデーターがあるとします。

```
foo<ほげほげ>bar<ふがふが>
```

ここから「ほげほげ」の部分だけを抽出したいです。ご存知の方が入ればお手数ですが宜しくおねがいします。

### 試したこと

```
echo "foo<ほげほげ>bar<ふがふが>" | grep -oP "(?<=foo<).*(?=>)"
```

--

```
echo "foo<ほげほげ>bar<ふがふが>" | sed -r 's/^.*foo<(.*)>.*$/\1/'
```

ですがどちらも「`ほげほげ>bar<ふがふが`」のように出力されてしまい、直近の閉じ括弧ではなく、同行の最後の閉じ括弧までを拾ってしまうようです。

Comment: non-greedy matching にすればよろしいかと。`grep -oP "(?<=foo<).*?(?=>)"`

Comment: ありがとうございます！できました。